# Lua pattern matching problem with escaped letter

Tags: lua, pattern-matching, lua-patterns

I've already had a rule that `\` should be replaced with `\\\\`
, so the existed code is

```
string.gsub(s, '\\', '\\\\\\\\')
```

but there is some data that should not be converted, such as `abc\"cba`, which will be replaced with `abc\\\\"cba`.

How can I constraint that only `\` followed without `"` can be replaced, such like

```
'abc\abc' -> 'abc\\\\abc'

'abc\"abc' -> 'abc\"abc'
```

I have used patterns like  `\\[^\"]-` and `\\[^\"]+-` but none of them works.

Thanks

Comment: If you do not expect ``\`` to appear at the end of string, you can use ``string.gsub(s, '\\([^"])', '\\\\\\\\%1') ``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```lua
string.gsub((s .. ' '), '\\([^"])', '\\\\\\\\%1'):sub(1, -2)
```

See the online demo:

```lua
local s = [[abc\abc abc\"abc\]];
s = string.gsub((s .. ' '), '\\([^"])', '\\\\\\\\%1'):sub(1, -2)
print( s );
-- abc\\\\abc abc\"abc\\\\
```

Notes:

- `\\([^"])` - matches two chars, a `\` and then any one char other than a `"` char (that is captured into Group 1)
- `\\\\\\\\%1` - replacement pattern that replaces each match with 4 backslashes and the value captured in Group 1
- `(s .. ' ')` - a space is appended at the end of the input string so that the pattern could consume a char other than a `"` char
- `:sub(1, -2)` - removes the last "technical" space that was added.

Comment: Yet another note: You may use long strings `[[\\\\]]` or simply `("\\"):rep(4)` to significantly shorten the eight backslashes.